# Servlet consuming http post parameters

Tags: java, rest, servlets, httpwebrequest

I am completely new to JAVA. I need to write a servlet which will consume http post parameters sent from a client. I already have a java application platform server and could deploy my applications there. What I need is to write a servlet which will react to posted parameters.

Apparently I will need to expose these variables in Servlet? I did google and came across results where it is suggested to use REST frameworks to achieve this.  Is this not possible writing plane java code (e.g. to be run Tomcat) without using any additional framework? A link to sample or tutorial would be helpful too.

Thanks

Comment: Try google search for Java servlets http://www.novocode.com/doc/servlet-essentials/

Comment: the question was about the absolute necessity to use REST. duffymo has provided an excellent explanation which probably took him 2 minutes to write with an awesome official tutorial (which is not I was getting from google or was not sure, is the best one)..  It probably was faster for him than downvoting - which in turn will sure help some newbies in Java. Thanks duffymo.

Comment: you also haven't provided what you have tried. IMHO, you didn't do much research. A google search for `java servlet post` shows tons of examples that do not use REST frameworks.

Comment: Or just checking the tag wiki page here on SO. Put the mouse above the `[servlets]` tag until a black box shows up and click therin the *info* link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need a REST framework.

Just write a servlet that extends `HttpServlet` and implements `doPost()`.

Start with the Sun/Oracle tutorial:

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava1/servlet.html

Here are the javadocs for the parent class:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build an app with jax-RS, you just need to include a few jars in your project before deploying to Tomcat. Your IDE may do this for you when it builds the war file. You can move these jars to the Tomcat lib folder if you want to decrease the size of your upload when you deploy. But you certainly don't need to use REST to access request parameters.

Practically all traditional Web apps need to capture http post parameters. I wrote a little utility servlet to list all of the parameters to help me prevent silly mistakes where I call the parameter by one name in the HTML and another name in the servlet. This code shows you how to get request and session parameters: (see [HttpServletRequest docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) )

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

/**
 * This Servlet contains some helpful debugging methods.
  * @author Leon LaSpina
 */
@WebServlet(name = "UtilityServlet", urlPatterns = {"/dev/Utility"})
public class UtilityServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * This is a utility method for displaying the list of all request parameters
     * sent to a Servlet or JSP.
     * @param request - The HTTP request sent to the Servlet or JSP
     * @param out The stream so that the method may write directly to the web page.
     */
    public static void printMap(HttpServletRequest request, PrintWriter out) {
        java.util.Map<String, String[]> paramMap = request.getParameterMap();
        out.println("<h3>From Data</h3>");
        out.println("<table border='1'><tr>");
        out.print("<td>attribte name</td><td>Attribute Data</td></tr>");
        String[] attribute;
        for (String name : paramMap.keySet()) {
            out.print("<tr>");
            out.println("<td>" + name + "</td><td>");
            attribute = paramMap.get(name);
            if (attribute.length == 1) {
                out.print(attribute[0]);
            } else {
                for (String s : attribute) {
                    out.print(s + ", ");
                }
            }
            out.println("</td></tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table>");
    }

    /**
     * This is a simple utility method for displaying the list of all Session
     * Objects in a simple table.
     * @param request - sent to servlet or JSP
     * @param out the OutputStream so that we may write directly to the web page
     */
    public static void printSessionMap(HttpServletRequest request, PrintWriter out) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        printSessionMap(session, out);
    }

    /**
     * This is a simple utility method for displaying the list of all Session
     * Objects in a simple table.
     * @param request - sent to servlet or JSP
     * @param out the OutputStream so that we may write directly to the web page
     */
    public static void printSessionMap(HttpSession session, PrintWriter out) {
        java.util.Enumeration<String> names = session.getAttributeNames();
        out.println("<h3>Session Objects</h3>");
        out.println("<table border='1'><tr>");
        out.print("<td>attribte</td><td>DataType</td><td>Object Data</td></tr>");
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            out.print("<tr><td>");
            String attribute = names.nextElement();
            out.print(attribute + "</td><td>");
            out.print(session.getAttribute(attribute).getClass().getName());
            out.print("</td><td>");
            out.println(session.getAttribute(attribute));
            out.println("</td></tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table>");
    }

    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //HttpSession theSession = request.getSession();
        try {
            out.println("<html><head>");
            out.println("<title>UtilityServlet</title></head>");
            out.println("<body><h1>UtilityServlet for development</h1>");
            printMap(request, out);
            printSessionMap(request, out);
            out.println("</body></html>");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```